# How to insert some data into MySQL when a photo is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

it is possible to insert in a database(e.g. MySQL) some values or informations like alt attribute when an image is clicked? How could I do that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/38176-how-to-insert-picture-in-mysql-database/

Comment: Do you mean the attributes of any Html elements or only the image tag's?

Comment: I want to make something like a rating but with some photos and I want to insert some values in the database when an image is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that easily with Jquery and some server side processing.

```
$("#myimage").click(function() {
   var $myimage=$(this);
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'myserverpage.php',
       data: { img_url: $myimage).attr('href'), 'img_alt': $myimage.attr('alt') },
       success: function(){
            console.log("OK!");
       }
   });
});
```

In your page `myserverpage.php` you can find the POST array the values you set in the Ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

take a look on the given example:

```
// Your Images With Click Event
$('img').click(function(){
   var altData = $(this).attr('alt');

   // Use Ajax request to insert data into database
   $.ajax({
     url: 'your_url_here', 
     data: 'alt='+altData, 
     success: function(data){ /* response by your url */ }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With ajax and better with jQuery:

[jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Use .click() to catch click event and then call a function doing ajax request on a php file that insert data into your database.

Answer (score 0):

hope this link will be useful to you...[jQuery ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

You can make an ajax call in 'onClick' event of the particular image :)